# appending to a slice in for loop with unexpected results

Tags: go, slice

It could be a silly question but when I try to append a []byte slice to a `[][]byte` slice I get weird results.

Here is my code:

```
func Normalizer(s string) (ss [][]byte) {

    ss = make([][]byte, 0)
    // norm
    var ia norm.Iter

    ia.InitString(norm.NFC, s)

    for !ia.Done() {

        next := ia.Next()

        fmt.Println(next)
        // [226 128 139]
        // [227 128 129]
        // [39]
        // [226 128 153]
        // [46]
        // [44]
        // [63]
        // [33]
        // [92]
        // [10]
        // [226 128 153]
        // ...
        ss = append(ss, next)

    }
    ia.Done()


    fmt.Println(ss)
    return
}
```

I'm expecting somethin like this:

```
// [[226 128 139] [227 128 129] [39] [226 128 153] [46] [44] [63] [33] [92] [10] [226 128 153]...]
```

but instead i get this:

```
// [[226 129 128] [226 129 128] [226] [226 129 128] [226] [226] [226] [226] [226] [226] [226 129 128]...]
```

and I have no idea why. Help and explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slice is a struct with a pointer to an underlying array, a length, and a capacity.

```
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

You are changing the underlying array after you have appended the slice struct. `ia.Next()` reuses its return buffer.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm"
)

func Normalizer(s string) (ss [][]byte) {
    ss = make([][]byte, 0)
    var ia norm.Iter
    ia.InitString(norm.NFC, s)
    for !ia.Done() {
        next := ia.Next()
        fmt.Println(string(next), &next[0])
        ss = append(ss, next)
    }
    fmt.Println()
    for i := range ss {
        fmt.Println(string(ss[i]), &ss[i][0])
    }
    fmt.Println()
    return
}

func main() {
    ss := Normalizer("abc")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", ss)
}
```

Output:

```
a 0xc420092228
b 0xc420092228
c 0xc420092228

c 0xc420092228
c 0xc420092228
c 0xc420092228

[c c c]
```

Replace a copy of a slice struct

```
next := ia.Next()
```

with a new slice struct with a new underlying array

```
next := append([]byte(nil), ia.Next()...)
```

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm"
)

func Normalizer(s string) (ss [][]byte) {
    ss = make([][]byte, 0)
    var ia norm.Iter
    ia.InitString(norm.NFC, s)
    for !ia.Done() {
        next := append([]byte(nil), ia.Next()...)
        fmt.Println(string(next), &next[0])
        ss = append(ss, next)
    }
    fmt.Println()
    for i := range ss {
        fmt.Println(string(ss[i]), &ss[i][0])
    }
    fmt.Println()
    return
}

func main() {
    ss := Normalizer("abc")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", ss)
}
```

Output:

```
a 0xc4200120d0
b 0xc4200120e8
c 0xc420012108

a 0xc4200120d0
b 0xc4200120e8
c 0xc420012108

[a b c]
```

References:

[Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)

[Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

Comment: It's golang's build in utf-8 string normalization lib.  https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm#Iter TL:DR; it returns `[]byte`